# How do I read C++ pointer construct?

Tags: c++, pointers

This is a newbie C++ question. What is the difference between the following two constructs?

```
1. const int* const* const x
2. const int**
```

How do I read these constructs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets a bit easier if you group things the right way. For example, `*const` is really one unit meaning "const pointer to" (you can read the `const` as a subscript here: `*const`). I'd write it as:

```
const int *const *const p1; // p1 is a const pointer to const pointer to const int
const int **p2; // p2 is a pointer to pointer to const int
```

Also remember that declarations read "inside out", starting at the identifier being declared.

Answer (score 8):

> How do I read these constructs?

Read them backwards and read the `*` as "pointer to".

```
const int* const* const
```

is a constant pointer to a constant pointer to an integer constant.

```
const int**
```

is a pointer to a pointer to an integer constant.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool that's useful/fun to decipher declarations: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/

In your case it reports: 
`const int* const* const x` => declare x as const pointer to const pointer to const int
`const int** x` => declare x as pointer to pointer to const int